# Проблема политики безопасности Flash приложения

Tags: node.js, socket.io, flash, websocket

Имеется **Node.js** сервер с установленной библиотекой **Socket.IO**. А так же **Flash** приложение, использующее для соединения с этим сервером библиотеку **socket.io-flash**

Если сервер находится в `localhost` — то при компиляции в *Flash Builder*, приложение подключается к серверу.

Если сервер находится по адресу (в интернете) `123.123.123.123:10081` - то при компиляции в *Flash Builder*, приложение тоже подключается к серверу.

Если я выкладываю приложение в Контакт, которое коннектится к адресу 123.123.123.123:10081 - приложение выдаёт ошибку политики безопасности.

Flash приложение первым делом (как я понимаю) запрашивает файл политики безопасности с порта 843. Тогда я поставил на **Node.js** библиотеку **FlashPolicyFileServer** и запустил её собственно на 843 порт для отдачи этого файла.

Вот код сервера:

```
    var pf = require('policyfile').createServer();
    pf.listen(843, function(){
        console.log(':: Server FlashSocketPolicyFile run ::');
    });

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(10081);
    //io.set('log level', 1);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Пользователь подключился: '+socket.id);

        socket.on('message', function(message, callback) {
            console.log('Сообщение: '+message+'   callback: '+callback);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Пользователь отключился: '+socket.id);
        });
    });

    console.log(':: Server run ::');
```

Но это не помогло, приложение, выложенное вконтакт, всё так же выдавало ошибку политики безопасности. При этом если перейти по адресу (в интернете) `123.123.123.123:843` — сервер выдавал файл политики безопасности:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**В чём может быть моя ошибка?!**

Comment: Мож я че не в тему скажу, но при мне флэш всегда искал файл `http://site.com/crossdomain.xml`, т.е. на 80 порту по запросу "GET /crossdomain.xml".

Comment: Мой (рабочий) файлик выглядит так:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <cross-domain-policy>
      <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    </cross-domain-policy>

Comment: Ошибся немного я, файл политики у меня выглядит так

<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/></cross-domain-policy>

Comment: лог ошибки можно глянуть?

Answer (score 1):

Код сервера тут не причем. Тебя сам Flash клиент просит поднять demon для отдачи policy file. Создай отдельно файлик policy.js. И стартуй его.

```
net = require("net");


function p(text) {
    var date = new Date();
    console.log('['+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds()+':'+date.getMilliseconds()+'] '+text);
}

function onConnect(socket) {


    socket.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
    socket.write("<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\n");
    socket.write("<!-- Policy file for xmlsocket://socks.mysite.com -->\n");
    socket.write("<cross-domain-policy>\n");
    socket.write("<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />\n");
    socket.write("</cross-domain-policy>\n");


    socket.end();

    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        p('Error policy file : '+err.stack);
    });

}
net.createServer(onConnect).listen(843);
```

Если ты делаешь игру для Вконтакте, то аватарки чтобы работали (со всех серверов).
Политик файл нужен http://site.com/crossdomain.xml.
Иначе с одного сервера будут показываться автарки, с другого нет.